# Import file from main folder to file in subsubfoler

Tags: python, python-import

I want import file from main folder to subsubfoler and use functions from there.

```
start.py
database.py
cogs/
    __init__.py
    Utility/
        __init__.py
        utility.py
```

Python can't import from database.py to utility.py and I don't know how can it works.
I used:

```
from ...database import Database
from database import Database
from ... import Database
```

How can I solved this problem? In future I add some folders in cogs.

Comment: There is a missing `__init__.py` at root level. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: I added and the same problem exist

Comment: Guess, you are running `utility.py` directly ?

Comment: When start utility.py directly have error `from database import Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

Python needs to know where to look for importable modules, and it searches `sys.path` for them. This can be manipulated from within python, or by setting the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` (examples are to follow). By default python adds the entrypoint's directory to `sys.path` at the first position (`sys.path` is a list), so while running scripts from the base directory would usually work with *absolute* imports nested under, running from a subdirectory and trying to *relatively* import upwards - will not. From python's docs regarding [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "**main**", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports.

This means that `start.py` will work if it `import cogs` (absolute), but neither `start.py` nor `utility.py` will work if they `from . [or .., or ...] import cogs` (relative).

### How to make it work

Consider the following directory structure (unchanged from the question, just placed under `/tmp/kacper/`):

```
/tmp/kacper/
├── start.py
├── database.py
└── cogs
    ├── __init__.py
    └── Utility
        ├── __init__.py
        └── utility.py
```

`__init__.py` files are empty, other file contents are as follows;

/tmp/kacper/database.py:

```
def Database():
    print("Function Database in file database.py")
```

/tmp/kacper/start.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from cogs.Utility.utility import Database

print("Done importing, now to start.py's code:")
Database()
print("Done with start.py's code")
```

/tmp/kacper/cogs/Utility/utility.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import os

    if 'PYTHONPATH' not in os.environ:
        print("No PYTHONPATH in env, adding project's root")
        this_file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        base = os.path.join(this_file_dir, "..", "..")
        sys.path.append(base)
    else:
        print("Found PYTHONPATH in env")
else:
    print("utility.py is imported, not touching sys.path")


from database import Database


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("In second main of utility.py")
    Database()
    print("Done second main of utility.py")
```

### Running

Now, as `start.py` resides in the base of the project, it just works:

```
$ /tmp/kacper/start.py
utility.py is imported, not touching sys.path
Done importing, now to start.py's code:
Function Database in file database.py
Done with start.py's code
```

But when directly calling `utility.py`, we have to either specify `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ PYTHONPATH="/tmp/kacper" /tmp/kacper/cogs/Utility/utility.py
Found PYTHONPATH in env
In second main of utility.py
Function Database in file database.py
Done second main of utility.py
```

or manipulate `sys.path` from within the script:

```
$ /tmp/kacper/cogs/Utility/utility.py
No PYTHONPATH in env, adding project's root
In second main of utility.py
Function Database in file database.py
Done second main of utility.py
```

If `PYTHONPATH` is not set correctly (or there's no internal handling of `sys.path`), this will fail; for example:

```
$ PYTHONPATH='/tmp' /tmp/kacper/cogs/Utility/utility.py
Found PYTHONPATH in env
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/kacper/cogs/Utility/utility.py", line 18, in <module>
    from database import Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database'
```

### Adding more stuff under cogs

Once python knows where to import from, this should be fairly simple. Consider the following directory structure:

```
/tmp/kacper/
├── database.py
├── start.py
└── cogs
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Utility
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── utility.py
    └── newCogsFolder
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── newCogsFunctionFile.py
        └── new_cogs_subfolder
            ├── __init__.py
            └── new_cogs_subfunction_file.py
```

/tmp/kacper/cogs/newCogsFolder/newCogsFunctionFile.py:

```
def newCogsFunction():
    print("new cogs function")
```

/tmp/kacper/cogs/newCogsFolder/new_cogs_subfolder/new_cogs_subfunction_file.py:

```
def new_cogs_subfunction():
    print("new cogs sub function")
```

Then you can add to `utility.py` (after the first `if` clause):

```
from cogs.newCogsFolder.new_cogs_subfolder.new_cogs_subfunction_file import new_cogs_subfunction
from cogs.newCogsFolder.newCogsFunctionFile import newCogsFunction
```

and to `start.py` you can mix and match (if it makes sense):

```
from cogs.Utility.utility import newCogsFunction
from cogs.newCogsFolder.new_cogs_subfolder.new_cogs_subfunction_file import new_cogs_subfunction
```

---

**Notes:**

- It usually is *not* a good idea to execute code during `import`s, and it is an even worse idea to `print` during them. The above code is just an example to demo the different cases.
- For convenience, the files `start.py` and `utility.py` are set as executables in the above example. The result would be no different with omitting the `#!/usr/bin/env python` line, and running `python /tmp/kacper/start.py` or `python /tmp/kacper/cogs/Utility/utility.py`.
- In the section *Adding more stuff under cogs*; the directory, file, and function names intentionally don't follow PEP8 - to show that naming schemes don't matter, as long as python can import them. Hint: don't use hyphens (`-`) in such names.
- In the section *Adding more stuff under cogs*; While showing that it is possible for `start.py` to mix between direct imports and importing from `utility.py`, this is a pattern that is best avoided. For clarity, maintainability, and continuity - one method should be chosen, according to the specific use-case.