# Import Python files into folders in folders

Tags: python

I am working on a project where I organise my file by this way :

```
  code /  text /   style.py
                        font.py
                        rendering.py
       
            button /  style.py
                        rendering.py


 data  /  images
           ...
           ...

 main.py
```

I need to import files in `main.py` such as `code/text/style.py`.
I tried using `__init__.py` files in `code/text` and `code/button` but it shows me "module 'code' has no attribute 'text'".

Please help me.

Programming is the only real pain on Earth.

Comment: How are you importing it in main.py?

Comment: I generally don't prefer init.py for module import as it imports unnecessary files as a whole. Instead use `from code.text.style import (yourclass/function/variables)` in your main.py.

Comment: @JeJe - How is pathlib going to help with an import issue?

Comment: @Immaturetrader - A empty `__init__.py` defines its containing directory as a package and holds that package's namespace. I'm not sure where "unnecessary files" comes from.

Comment: missread. so import code.text.style.* doesn't work from main.py? what is your code?

Comment: It looks like you did `import code` and then did `print(code.text)`. That's how you'd get the `AttributeError: module 'code' has no attribute 'text'`. But you really need to show us the exact code that failed and the error that was generated. Otheriwse everything is pure speculation.

Comment: Make a test file at the same level as main.py. `test.py` holding just `import code.text.style`. Add empty `code/__init__.py` and `code/test/__init__.py`. Does test.py work?

Comment: when you say import files you mean import content of the files (functions, classes etc)? that's why I got confused...

Comment: can you share the code you tried and used in main.py? have you tried my import one liner?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import file from main folder to file in subsubfoler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74816575/import-file-from-main-folder-to-file-in-subsubfoler)

Comment: Please [edit] and post all your code, especially the imports and files `main.py` and `__init__` as [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an empty `__init__.py` file in every folder during the path:

```
├── code
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── text
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── style.py
```

Comment: This is true, but i think from the error message that OP has the wrong `import` statement also. We'll see if we get more info.

Comment: Maybe you could add a one-line `main.py` that does `import code.text.style` to show how it works.

Comment: as well is main.py at the root...? does he use an env/how the app is launched?

Comment: It finally worked, I renamed `code` to `src`, I put `from . import text` in `src/__init__.py` and `from . import font` in `src/text/__init__.py`.